# Can i transfer files between two rapberry pi's using Aux cable?

Tags: raspbian, rpi.gpio, serial

As a part of project, i have to transfer any file from one pi to another pi through Aux cable.

Comment: Ah, I forgot what is aux cable. I think it is easy to transfer using serial/UART cable, more difficult using SPI cable, very difficult using I2C and Ethernet cable. And if your files are very small, you can "transfer" using jumper wire connecting two Rpi's GPIO pins, Or using BlueTooth, or WiFi, or radio frequencies 400/900MHz, 2.4GHz etc. Let me know the file size, desired speed, and I will try to give more details.  If you have no idea, I would recommend with Rpi built in serial cable, or USB to serial cables.

Comment: And I ask Quora what is aux cable: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-meaning-of-AUX. So it is for audio visual signals. I have not heard about how to transfer files MP3, or MP4 etc. Perhaps I should let others to answer.

Comment: Not if you plan to use the built-in headphone jack for that task.

Comment: Related links – https://superuser.com/questions/1018664/on-linux-can-i-copy-a-file-using-a-headphone-jack-audio-cable-and-microphone-j  – https://www.reddit.com/r/ECE/comments/5xdlca/could_you_in_theory_send_files_through_a_35mm/